# How to init vars in fortran module using data

Tags: fortran

I have a module writen in f90 and some legacy init data code:

```
module example
implicit none
integer a


! my legacy data init value
!DEC$ NOFREEFORM

     data a /1/

!DEC$ FREEFORM

end module example
```

It compiled OK, but in the runtime, data statement seems not work, the var `a`'s value is 0 not 1.

What is the right way to insert legacy data statement into my f90 code?

```
program main
use example

print *, a
end program main
```

In this case if I remove the `!DEC$` line, I will got 1 in out put.

But I have a huge number of legacy code in real project, and do not want to upgrade the f77 code to f90.

My compiler is intel fortran 2013 on windows.

*update*

The space number before data is wrong. It changes to 5 after copy and paste, but actually, the syntax need 6 space here.

But Intel fortran does not raise any syntax error here.

After add spaces manually, the example code works.

BTW, the code works with gfrotran is just because `!DEC$ NOFREEFORM` attribute seems not recognized by gfortran.

Comment: Can you show a complete program which writes out the value of a as zero, please?

Comment: Please also specify the compiler and version used.

Comment: @IanBush, I have edited the question, the main program is as simple as possible.

Comment: @albert, thanks for this hint! I rebuild the code on linux with gfortran, it works well, but with intel fortran on windows, it got the wrong result.

Comment: "intel fortran 2013 on windows" a bit old would be nice to know what happens with the current Intel compiler and whether or not something is mentioned in the release notes of the newer versions.

Comment: I assume that your actual program is much larger, but I still would advise to remove the `!DEC$ NOFREEFORM` etc. as a mix of free format and fixed format code will always result in nightmares (as you now saw with different compilers, see your edit). Just stick to 1 format (preferably free format).

Answer (score -1):

This is more an extended comment - will either delete once a proper answer is in place, or edit once I work out the details I don't currently understand.

I don't have access to intel fortran 2013 on windows. However I do have access to

```
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 14.0.2 20140120
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

which I believe is the equivalent linux version. Trying this with your orginal code I get

```
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ cat data.f90
module example
implicit none
integer a


! my legacy data init value
!DEC$ NOFREEFORM

     data a /1/

!DEC$ FREEFORM

end module example
program main
use example

print *, a
end program main
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 14.0.2 20140120
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort data.f90 
data.f90(9): remark #5082: Directive ignored - Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'ATAA' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;
     data a /1/
------^
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$
```

This is occurring because you haven't indented the data statement enough for fixed format Fortran - it should be indented to column 7, but you have only got it to column 6. It is thus seeing the letter `d` as a continuation mark rather than as part of `data` and so getting very confused.

If I correct this the code works as expected:

```
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ cat data.f90
module example
implicit none
integer a


! my legacy data init value
!DEC$ NOFREEFORM
C234567
      data a /1/

!DEC$ FREEFORM

end module example
program main
use example

print *, a
end program main
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 14.0.2 20140120
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ifort data.f90 
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$ ./a.out
           1
[ijb@login12(arcus-b) stack]$
```

Now gfortran works because it is ignoring the compiler directive, and the data statement as originally written is perfectly valid free format Fortran. What I don't understand is why it compiles under Windows with ifort 2013